# Lenovo black screen and do not show charging

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, lenovo-laptop

I have a huge problem with my lenovo B5400 with Win7.
On the power adapter without battery it works ok. But when I plug in the battery and it is charging, Windows does not show the charging icon, but when the battery is at 100%, the screen goes black and the fan goes to 100% and the shutdown button stops responding, the only way to shut down the laptop is to pull out the battery. I thought it was the battery (its from 2014), but I ordered a replacement and the same thing is happening.
What could be wrong? KBC?

Comment: Most likely a charging circuit error.  I suggest getting it properly serviced.

Comment: @John very possible but its weird that it only has problem when its around 100%. I also tested different charger but with no result